# ReactJS - react-router history gets warning

Tags: javascript, routes, reactjs, browser-history, react-router

I've tried to clean my app's url following [these](http://rackt.org/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html) instructions.
I see it's not recommended, but I don't like that `?_k=ckuvup` in my url.

Everything's seems fine, until I've clicked twice one of my links

```
<Link className="menu-link" to="/test">Test Page</Link>
```

After that I see in my console this warning:

```
Warning: You cannot PUSH the same path using hash history
```

I still didn't find any solution about this, maybe I've confused something and the fact that's not recommended is explanatory, but I'd like to understand from where comes this.

Comment: use the browser history instead

Comment: Very clear, thank you all. The only problem it's that now i need a `server side` source, and I was developing this app just for a demo with only `static data`. Is there a way to maintain the `hash` navigation?

Comment: You can use a memory history for the server side of things (`createMemoryHistory()`)

Comment: for this particular case i don't want to call pages from server because this app has static pages, but this warning still appears to me if i double click on a menu link

Comment: The warning wouldn't appear if you will use `<a>` instead of `<Link>`. In case of react router v4 it works, all context is updated correctly.